# Determine whether two matrices are similiar

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

Question as above photo. I know two similiar matrices have same characteristic polynomial. The I found a = 2 or -2 and both 2 and -2 are similiar. So are my solution is right? If not, please point it out, Thanks.

Comment: Having the same characteristic polynomial is necessary, but not sufficient: $\small{\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}}$ and $\small{\pmatrix{1&1\\0&1}}$ have the same characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Please include critical parts of your question as text instead of posting pictures of it. Images are neither searchable nor accessible to screen readers, nor do they show up in summaries. You can find a quick reference for formatting mathematical expressions in MathJax [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).